# Understanding the notation for Joint Discrete Random Variables

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I am learning Joint Discrete Random Variables and am having a hard time understanding the notation.

[image]

Whats the difference between the capital X and Y and the lower case x and y?

Are we saying its the probability that the output of one function equals x and the other equals y?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$X$ is the random value, $x$ is a value $X$ can take.

Formally, $X$ is a function of an alea:
$$X:\Omega\to A$$
and $x$ is one element of $a$.

For example, $X$ can be tomorrow's temperature, and $x = 20$ degrees.

And for the second point, it is true: $f_{X,Y}(x,y)$ is
the probability that the $(X,Y)$ equals $(x,y)$.